# Overriding a templated Button's Command in WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, button, command

I have a `ControlTemplate` that I'm using to change the appearance and behavior of several `Button`s. I only want part of the `Button` to be clickable and to execute the bound `Command`, so I added a `Button` within the `ControlTemplate` and bound it to the template's `Command` property.

The problem I'm having is that since I am defining the `Command` binding on the templated `Button`, it executes regardless of which part of the template I am clicking.

In the below example you can click the `Border` and execute the `Command`. How do I change it so that the `Command` only executes when you click the `Button` within the template?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Button
            Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
            CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}" >
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Button>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

...

<Button
    Command="{Binding Path=SomeViewmodelCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SomeViewmodelCommandParameter}"
    Content="Click"
    Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" />
```

I don't think I can template a different element (like the `Border`) because I still need to pass in the `Command` somehow, and attached properties would still give me the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's a dirty hack, but you can bind the inner button's `Command` property to the templated parent's `Tag` property instead. That way you 'hide' the command from the containing button, but the inner button secretly knows how to get to it.

You can leave the `CommandParameter` as is, since it has no effect by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to re-template another control, such as Border and use a RoutedCommand on the Button inside the template. You could bind it to one of the built-in RoutedCommands, such as ApplicationCommands.Save and in the XAML for the containing control, add a CommandBinding for that particular command. Let me know if some code would be helpful.